# A command to be executed after a certain period of time

Tags: scheduledtask

I want to know the command that is executed after a certain period of time.

I guess `Pause` is a good choice for my purpose.
For instance, I tried to let the Mathematica do a job after 5 hours:

```
Pause[3600*5 (* 3600 seconds is 1 hour *)]
1+1
```

This code does not work, because after 5 hours I saw Mathematica was still pausing!

I confirmed the above code works if I choose a time around few minutes.

Any ideas would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Which *Mathematica* version do you use? I don't have this problem with version 13.0.0 on Windows 10 x64: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2yfs.png).

Comment: I am using version 12.3.1 on Mac OS Big Sur. I saw your screenshot. Your code runs after only 5min. I guess that my PC will be in sleep mode when leaving it for 5 "hours". I expect that I don't have this problem if I turn off the sleep mode.

Comment: Probably with `RunScheduledTask` you will have the same problem when the PC will be in sleep mode...

Comment: That 's right. Now, I realized that the problem was not in a specific command in mathematica, but in sleep mode...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use scheduled tasks.  Also, they do not hold up processing while waiting to activate :  As demonstrated below, `x` continues to update while the message displays and then disappears.

```
x = 0;
Dynamic[x]

Module[{},
 If[True,
  message = CreateDialog[TextCell[Style[
      "\n      Your message here.      \n\n", 18]],
    WindowFloating -> True];
  RunScheduledTask[NotebookClose[message], {1.5}]];
 Array[If[Mod[#, 100] == 0, x = #] &, 2000000];]
```

Comment: "RunScheduledTask" works fine! Thank you for your help!